# List of NLP challenges

Tags: nlp, reference-request

Is there any comprehensive list of past, current and future NLP challenges?

E.g. for NLP conferences, [Joel Tetreault's unofficially official conference calendar](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~tetreaul/conferences.html) and [WikiCFP](http://www.wikicfp.com/cfp/call?conference=natural%20language%20processing) are pretty good.

The ["Competitions and Challenges" page on the ACL wiki](http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Competitions_and_Challenges) quite incomplete.

Comment: I don't know of a comprehensive list, but for now Kaggle has an open NLP competition. They tend to appear regularly on their website.

Comment: The Allen Institute for Artificial Intelligence (AI2) challenge is currently live on Kaggle. https://www.kaggle.com/c/the-allen-ai-science-challenge  I suppose the dataset will remain there after the competition has ended in case anyone needs it.

Comment: @wacax Thanks, do some Kaggle contests sometimes remove the data sets after the end of the contest?

Comment: Not really, as far as I know. However this particular challenge does have a restriction, that the questions in this contest should not be published or shared and should only be used for your work in the competition. More info here: https://www.kaggle.com/c/the-allen-ai-science-challenge/forums/t/16891/reminder-questions-in-this-contest-should-not-be-published-or-shared

Comment: @wacax FYI [Do some Kaggle contest organizers remove the data sets after the end of the contest?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/6596/1652)

Answer (score 5):

List of NLP [competitions](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions) on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/) by popularity [number of teams]:

- Two Sigma Connect: Rental Listing Inquiries [2709 teams]
  https://www.kaggle.com/c/two-sigma-connect-rental-listing-inquiries
- Home Depot Product Search Relevance [2125 teams]
  https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-depot-product-search-relevance
- Quora Question Pairs [2123 teams]
  https://www.kaggle.com/c/quora-question-pairs
- What's Cooking? [1388 teams] https://www.kaggle.com/c/whats-cooking
- Crowdflower Search Results Relevance [1326 teams]
  https://www.kaggle.com/c/crowdflower-search-relevance
- Bag of Words Meets Bags of Popcorn [578 teams]
  https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial
- Transfer Learning on Stack Exchange Tags [380 teams]
  https://www.kaggle.com/c/transfer-learning-on-stack-exchange-tags/data
- Facebook Recruiting III - Keyword Extraction [367 teams] https://www.kaggle.com/c/facebook-recruiting-iii-keyword-extraction

  - *New entrants are prohibited, you won't be able to download data for this competition*
- Dato: Truly Native? [274 teams] https://www.kaggle.com/c/dato-native
- The Allen AI Science Challenge [170 teams]
  https://www.kaggle.com/c/the-allen-ai-science-challenge

Comment: Neat. Maybe ordering by end-date would be more useful.